# How can I use a Bash array as input to a command?

Tags: arrays, bash, newline, pipe

Say, for example, I have the following array:

```
files=( "foo" "bar" "baz fizzle" )
```

I want to pipe the contents of this array through a command, say `sort`, as though each element where a line in a file. Sure, I could write the array to a temporary file, then use the temporary file as input to `sort`, but I'd like to avoid using a temporary file if possible.

If `"bar fizzle"` didn't have that space character, I could do something like this:

```
echo ${files[@]} | tr ' ' '\012' | sort
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sort <(for f in "${files[@]}" ; do echo "$f" ; done)
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know about the `<()` syntax. Thanks Ignacio!

Comment: I also didn't know (until now) that `"${files[@]}"` expands to `"foo" "bar" "baz fizzle"` rather than `"foo bar baz fizzle"`.

Comment: What is this particular method called?

Answer (score 7):

Yet another solution:

```
printf "%s\n" "${files[@]}" | sort
```

Comment: Although this works, it seems to rely on poorly documented behavior of printf: the fact that, unlike in the C version of printf, the printf command line utility loops over the format string until there are no more arguments. If you look at [the man page for printf(1) under Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/printf.1.html), it talks about this in the BUGS section. I'll still give you the vote though ;)

Comment: @splicer: I think the note in the BUGS section is talking about something else; the main DESCRIPTION section says "The format string is reused as often as necessary to satisfy the arguments."  The [bash(1) man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html) has a similar note on its printf builtin.

Answer (score 3):

```
SAVE_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
echo "${files[*]}" | sort
IFS=$SAVE_IFS
```

Of course it won't work properly if there are any newlines in array values.

Answer (score 2):

For sorting files I would recommend sorting in zero-terminated mode (to avoid errors in case of embedded newlines in file names or paths):

```
files=(
$'fileNameWithEmbeddedNewline\n.txt'
$'saneFileName.txt'
)

echo ${#files[@]}

sort <(for f in "${files[@]}" ; do printf '%s\n' "$((i+=1)): $f" ; done)
sort -z <(for f in "${files[@]}" ; do printf '%s\000' "$((i+=1)): $f" ; done) | tr '\0' '\n'

printf "%s\000" "${files[@]}" | sort -z | tr '\0' '\n'
find . -type f -print0 | sort -z | tr '\0' '\n'
```

`sort -z` **reads & writes** zero-terminated lines!

Comment: @splicer NUL-terminated is still safest for lists of data, many programs are capable of using & producing them.

Answer (score 1):

I like to wrap common items like this into function to make it easier to understand what's going on:

```bash
pipeArray() {
    for ITEM in $@; do
        echo "$ITEM"
    done
}

DATA=('a' 'c' 'b')
pipeArray ${DATA[@]} | sort
```